# Ionic2/Angular2 - Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _ionicAngular.Pipe) is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic2, pipes-filters

I am working on an Ionic2 app. Now, I am trying to implement a custom pipe; however, I receive the following error when doing so:

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _ionicAngular.Pipe) is not a function

So far, here is my code:

```
import {Page, Pipe, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';


    //Phone formatting pipe
    @Pipe({
        name: 'phone'
    })
    export class PhonePipe{
        transform(val, args) {
            val = val.charAt(0) != 0 ? '0' + val : '' + val;
            let newStr = '';

            for(i=0; i < (Math.floor(val.length/2) - 1); i++){
               newStr = newStr+ val.substr(i*2, 2) + '-';
               console.log(val);
            }
            return newStr+ val.substr(i*2);
        }
    }
    /////


    @Page({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/outlet/outlet.html',
        pipes: [PhonePipe]
    })

    export class place {
      static get parameters() {
        return [[NavController],[NavParams]];
      }
      constructor(nav, navParams) {

      }
    }
```

outlet.html

```
<ion-content id="contentPadding" padding class="outlet">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="bigTitle">{{outletPhoneValue | phone}}</div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

When trying to implement Pipe in the following way:

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';
```

The first error disappear; however, a second error appears:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: val.charAt is not a function in [{{outletPhoneValue | phone}} in place@28:25]

Any idea on what's causing the error?

Comment: How do you use the pipe?

Comment: I've edited the post, please check how I use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Pipe` class must be imported from `angular2/core` and not `ionic-angular`:

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';
```

Comment: I've already done that before, but it gave me the following error: 
EXCEPTION: TypeError: val.charAt is not a function in [{{outletPhoneValue | phone}} in place@28:25]

Comment: I guess that `outPhoneValue` is received asynchronously so you need to check if `val` is null / undefined. If it's the case return `val` directly. Otherwise do your processing...

Comment: It's true that it is received async, but the variable is loaded even before the condition. To make sure I've setup a explicit variable doing: var val = 25565775; and got the same error. I've added an if condition too to check the null/undefined, and still I ended up with the same error!

Comment: Okay ;-) What is type of `outletPhoneValue`? A string or something else?

Comment: A number, I believe that it needs to be converted .toString() in order to work!